# Orbeon 4.0.0.m6 : How to set default language for form builder?

Tags: orbeon

I am in the progress of upgrading my code from Orbeon 3.9 to 4.0.0.m6 . I want to be the form builder in German by default, for 3.9 I deleted all translations in `src/resources/apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml` and `src/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/form/resources.xml` and added German translations. This doesn't seem to work in 4.0 anymore, it complains about missing translations (I see an error message like `empty sequence is not allowed for format-message`).

I tried to add the following line to my properties, but that doesn't help either:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.default-language.*.*" value="de"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.available-languages.*.*" value="de"/>
```

As far as I see the form builder still tries to look for English translations, although only German translations are present. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution! You need to set this property:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.available-languages.orbeon.builder"
    value="de"/>
```

It's not enough to set it with wildcards:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.available-languages.*.*"
    value="de"/>
```

because Orbeon Forms ships with a default value for this property already:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.available-languages.orbeon.builder"
    value="en fr"/>
```

Because wildcards are weaker than more specific properties, specifying explicitly `oxf.fr.available-languages.orbeon.builder` is required.

With this, you probably don't even need the following property:

```
<property
     as="xs:string"
     name="oxf.fr.default-language.orbeon.builder"
     value="de"/>
```

On the other hand, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Weird, switching to French works like a charm. So it doesn't work anymore to add a new language just by editing `src/resources/apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml` and `src/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/form/resources.xml`? Do I need to provide translations for all XBL components? Or do I have to add the language to a specific config file?

Comment: The language selection logic only looks at the Form Runner resources and the form's resources, not the XBL components' resources. So I am surprised it doesn't work! There is no particular magic for English or French besides the fact that they are defined.

Comment: I spent some more time on this topic but I can't figure out why this isn't working. I uploaded the resources.xml files and my config to https://gist.github.com/5e73afb28c32aa607eb4 , could you try out if this is working for you? I had no problems with Orbeon 3.9, the problems occured with version 4 for the first time...

Comment: Iacco, sorry I haven't yet had time to look at this but will try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the problem was caused by some offensive character codes in Iacco's src/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/form/resources.xml. I have uploaded a revised version on git://gist.github.com/3304742 which works fine for me (using Orbeon 4.0.0.m7).

Thank you, Iacco, for sharing your translations! I added some more (and also did a few modifications).